# Ansible set password for complete play

Tags: passwords, ansible, privileges

I am using Ansible to define a lot of tasks which needs sudo privileges(user running tasks is a non root user who is a member of sudo group)  . To do so I have been using following code every time defining `become`, `become_method` and `become_pass` .

```
# This is a sample task which needs sudo privileges
- name: copy the dnsmasq file
  template: src="templates/dnsmasq.conf" dest="/etc/dnsmasq.conf" owner="{{ROOT_USER}}" mode="0644" group="{{ROOT_USER}}"
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_pass: "{{ remote_user_password }}"
  notify: Restart dnsmasq
```

I want to set the following attributes at play level `become`, `become_method` and `become_pass` . I can set become, become_method but I get `ERROR: become_pass is not a legal parameter of an Ansible Play` which of course makes sense but then whats the attribute to define password at play level ?

I also tried privilege escalation using `ansible_become=yes  ansible_become_method=sudo  ansible_become_user=MY_NON_ROOT_USER ansible_become_pass=My_PASSWD` in ansible_hosts  file(where we define host) but it still does not allow the tasks to run without sudo and gives permission denied.

Is there a way I can define one time password for a playbook to run in non-interactive way so that I don't have to define become attributes for each and every task .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use :

**deploy.yml**

```
- name: Todo something
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  become_method: su
```

When you execute the playbook pass the password like a extra var.

```
 --extra-vars='ansible_become_pass=password'
```

Comment: Is becoming root only the way ? I don't want to perform the tasks using the root user. I will try using it via normal user and would see if it works

Comment: No root is not the only way. It works with other users too.

Comment: rather then passing the `ansible_become_pass` I simply mentioned the attribute `ansible_become_pass` in hosts file .Also the two attributes `become: yes` , `become_method: sudo` at top below the hosts since I only have single host .  Thanks a lot .